# Footer en TCPDF

Tags: php, css, tcpdf

Deseo poder agregar un texto simple al final de pie de cada hoja, he intentado editarlo pero no logro obtener lo deseado (Ver en la foto.)

```
public function Footer() {
    $cur_y = $this->y;
    $text ="<p>*Se cotiza solo lo detallado, cualquier modificación sera sujeta a un nuevo presupuesto</p>
    <p>*Esta cotización se acepta en conjunto con hoja condiciones comerciales y especificaciones técnicas que deben ser aceptadas y firmada por el cliente.</p>";
    $this->SetTextColorArray($this->footer_text_color);
    //set style for cell border
    $line_width = (1.55 / $this->k);
    $this->SetLineStyle(array('width' => $line_width, 'cap' => 'butt', 'join' => 'miter', 'dash' => 0, 'color' => $this->footer_line_color));
    //print document barcode
    $barcode = $this->getBarcode();
    if (!empty($barcode)) {
        $this->Ln($line_width);
        $barcode_width = round(($this->w - $this->original_lMargin - $this->original_rMargin) / 3);
        $style = array(
            'position' => $this->rtl?'R':'L',
            'align' => $this->rtl?'R':'L',
            'stretch' => false,
            'fitwidth' => true,
            'cellfitalign' => '',
            'border' => false,
            'padding' => 0,
            'fgcolor' => array(0,100,100),
            'bgcolor' => false,
            'text' => false
        );
        $this->write1DBarcode($barcode, 'C128', '', $cur_y + $line_width, '', (($this->footer_margin / 3) - $line_width), 0.3, $style, '');
    }
    $w_page = isset($this->l['w_page']) ? $this->l['w_page'].' ' : '';
    if (empty($this->pagegroups)) {
        $pagenumtxt = $w_page.$this->getAliasNumPage().' / '.$this->getAliasNbPages();
    } else {
        $pagenumtxt = $w_page.$this->getPageNumGroupAlias().' / '.$this->getPageGroupAlias();
    }
    $pagenumtxt = $text." ".$pagenumtxt;
    $this->SetY($cur_y);
    //Print page number
    if ($this->getRTL()) {
        $this->SetX($this->original_rMargin);
        $this->Cell(0, 0, $pagenumtxt, 'T', 0, 'L');
    } else {
        $this->SetX($this->original_lMargin);
        $this->Cell(0, 0, $this->getAliasRightShift().$pagenumtxt, 'T', 0, 'R');
    }
}
```

Foto con mi código
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Foto como deseo
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: @Marcos No me funciono =/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para personalizar el `footer` de la librería `tcpdf`, puedes tomar el **ejemplo 003** y modificarlo de la siguiente manera:

```
// Extend the TCPDF class to create custom Header and Footer
class MYPDF extends TCPDF {

    //Page header
    public function Header() {
        // Logo
        $image_file = K_PATH_IMAGES.'logo_example.jpg';
        $this->Image($image_file, 10, 10, 15, '', 'JPG', '', 'T', false, 300, '', false, false, 0, false, false, false);
        // Set font
        $this->SetFont('helvetica', 'B', 20);
        // Title
        $this->Cell(0, 15, '<< TCPDF Example 003 >>', 0, false, 'C', 0, '', 0, false, 'M', 'M');
    }

    // Page footer
    public function Footer() {
        // Position at 15 mm from bottom
        $this->SetY(-15);
        // Set font
        $this->SetFont('helvetica', '', 8);
        // Custom footer HTML
        $this->html = '<hr><br><span>*Se cotiza solo lo detallado, cualquier modificación sera sujeta a un nuevo presupuesto.</span><br><span>*Esta cotización se acepta en conjunto con hoja condiciones comerciales y especificaciones técnicas que deben ser aceptadas y firmada por el cliente.</span>';
        $this->writeHTML($this->html, true, false, true, false, '');
    }
}
```

**Haz énfasis en estas líneas:**

```
// Custom footer HTML
$this->html = '<hr><br><span>*Se cotiza solo lo detallado, cualquier modificación sera sujeta a un nuevo presupuesto.</span><br><span>*Esta cotización se acepta en conjunto con hoja condiciones comerciales y especificaciones técnicas que deben ser aceptadas y firmada por el cliente.</span>';
$this->writeHTML($this->html, true, false, true, false, '');
```

Como puedes ver, el código `html` tiene algunas diferencias con el que tienes actualmente:

- Debe quedar **en una sola línea** y **encerrado en comillas simples**.
- No utilicé etiquetas de tipo párrafo `<p></p>` ya que agregan saltos de línea que dejarían el segundo comentario fuera del `footer`. En su lugar utilicé `<span></span>` y controlé el salto de línea con `<br>`
- Utilicé un `<hr>` pero solo con fines ilustrativos para mostrar la salida. *Veo que ya tienes resuelto lo del color de la línea, así que lo puedes omitir.*

La salida debe quedar similar a esta imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si deseas mostrar el número de página, basta con agregar este código al final de `$this->html`

```
<b>página'.$this->getAliasNumPage().'/'.$this->getAliasNbPages().'</b>'
```

Quedando la línea completa de esta manera:

```
$this->html = '<hr><br><span>*Se cotiza solo lo detallado, cualquier modificación sera sujeta a un nuevo presupuesto.</span><br><span>*Esta cotización se acepta en conjunto con hoja condiciones comerciales y especificaciones técnicas que deben ser aceptadas y firmada por el cliente. </span><b>página'.$this->getAliasNumPage().'/'.$this->getAliasNbPages().'</b>';
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Gracias x la respuesta, pero lo logro de otra forma